# How important are Yahrtzeit customs?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, minhag, yahrtzeit, psychology

Many people regard Yahrtzeit customs and observances with much reverence and importance. The psychological reasons for this are self-evident, as such observances provide people with a feeling of connection to their deceased relatives and loved ones.

Is there any halachic basis for the importance accorded to Yahrtzeit observances, other than the psychological aspect of it? For example, if one derives no psychological satisfaction from Yahrtzeit observances, is there any halachic reason for him to perform them anyway?

Comment: Surely you could apply this question to any of the dearth of minhagim we have and not just Yahrzeit customs?

Comment: If I don't find Kitniyot meaningful, is there any reason to abide by it?

Comment: @Double AA - the practice of avoiding kitniyot is/was based on clear halachic factors, which have nothing to do with one's personal feelings. Are there any such factors for Yahrtzeyt observances?

Comment: I don't understand what that means or why it matters

Comment: I think your ending answers the question. The reason for the Halachah is to observe it. You could find it easily in the Talmud where it describes different behaviors of single Rabbis (R' X did that and R' Y did that) and all of sudden it is codified by Rambam as an obligating Halacha. Same here, some Rabbis start keeping different traditions of Yahrtzeit, and slowly it became a Halachah.

Comment: @Tesvov- I am not sure how you are reacting to the comments but typically, on this list, there seems to be a tradition to downcast a perfectly normal question that was asked in earnest and respect. I tried to give an answer below and my point here is that there is nothing wrong with what you're asking.

Comment: @Geltman is it perfectly normal to ask "I don't like this custom; do I really need to keep it?" Not sure every permutation of that is such a valuable post for our site

Comment: @DoubleAA - you are using a straw man argument there.

Comment: @Tesvov only if there's a meaningful difference between your question and mine. I don't see one.

Comment: @DoubleAA - a similar question would be something like: "The custom of putting a blech under the cholent pot is due to the fact that one may need to take it off and replace it during shabbos. If I know this situation does not apply to me, does it still make sense to keep this custom?" Your comment about not liking customs is not similar to the question at hand.

Comment: @Tesvov I don't understand how your comment responded to mine

Comment: @DoubleAA - you compared my question to "I don't like this custom; do I really need to keep it?" I'm answering that the question is not about liking yorhtzayt observances or not liking them. The question is whether the purpose of the observance is for the psychological benefit of the one observing it or whether there is another reason. That's why I brough the example with the custom of using a blech for cholent, which may or may not apply based on a particular situation.

Comment: Those all seem the same. If I ask if I can drop it because I don't like it, that's the same as asking if I need to keep it anyway because there is some other reason besides my satisfaction. Two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason behind the halachah which is not connected to one's personal feelings. If you look in the sefer [Gesher Hachaim chapter 32:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&st=&pgnum=306) he states that based on the writings of the Ari, davening on the yartzeit for the deceased "helps them ascend in gan eden to a higher level". Also a son has "weakened mazel" on the yartzeit [and apparently he helps himself by doing whatever is done on the yartzeit]. It is worthwhile to read that first chapter to get the whole idea in context but at least it shows that things are done without focusing on the psychological aspect behind it and are required to be done despite one may not relate to it or wish to do it.

Comment: Things being done doesn't imply things must be done. But your general point that there have been reasons given which aren't purely psychological is true. Whether those are enough to force someone to do things or to attach any high level of importance to the actions is still debatable. Some things have reasons and still are optional or still are not so important.

Comment: @DoubleAA - it's easier to evaluate the level of a custom''s importance when we know the underlying reason for it. Without a given reason, how can we properly prioritize any conflict between one custom and another?